# Ignore local .npmrc config file during npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

How do I ignore a local .npmrc config file while running `npm install`?

Is there a command like `npm install --ignore-local-rc` or something similar? I feel this can be useful for situations where you want to pull packages from the public npm registry by-passing the private registries specified.

Comment: Have you tried the `.npmignore`?

Comment: No I haven't, are you suggesting I add the .npmrc file to .npmignore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`--userconfig` or `--globalconfig`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#npmrc-files) to bypass the local user config file or global config file respectively. I don't think there is a way to bypass a project `.npmrc` with a command-line flag. Using `--userconfig=/dev/null` should bypass the userconfig (on Linux and other UNIX-like operating systems).

For situations where you need to bypass only the registry setting, you can use [the `--reg` or `--registry` command line flags](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties), or set an [`npm_config_registry` environment variable](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables).

Comment: Thanks Trott, using the --reg flag seems to be the way to go for now.